Problem How to Properly Initialize Swiper Component in React to Resolve "Cannot read properties of null" Error Upon Page Refresh
Can any one tell me why when I refresh a page I get this error for swiper?
import React, { useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import { register } from "swiper/element/bundle";
import "swiper/swiper-bundle.css";
import { SwiperElements, SwiperProps } from "./types";

declare global {
  namespace JSX {
    interface IntrinsicElements extends SwiperElements {}
  }
}

export const PzSwiper: React.FC<SwiperProps> = (props) => {
  const { children, ...rest } = props;
  const swiperRef = useRef<HTMLLinkElement | any>(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    register();

    const params = {
      ...rest,
    };
    if (swiperRef.current) {
      Object.assign(swiperRef.current, params);
      if (
        swiperRef.current &&
        typeof swiperRef.current.initialize === "function"
      ) {
        swiperRef.current.initialize();
      }
    } else {
      console.error("swiperRef.current is null");
    }
  }, [rest]);

  return (
    <swiper-container init="false" ref={swiperRef}>
      {children}
    </swiper-container>
  );
};

export const PzSlider: React.FC<SwiperProps> = (props) => {
  const { children, ...rest } = props;

  return <swiper-slide {...rest}>{children}</swiper-slide>;
};



I'm trying to use swiperElement in my nextjs 14 project and I get the above error when I refresh the page what should I do?
I have no idea what happen here?
